# Importing Twitter4j into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter4j

I've imported the 4 twitter4j jar files into my project through the java build path, but when I import twitter4j.Twitter; & import twitter4j.TwitterFactory; I get a run-time error? The last two lines of code where the objects are declared have a red underline due to the imports not[enter image description here][2] working. When I highlight the first two import lines, I get "The package twitter4j is accessible from more than one module: org.twitter4j.core, twitter4j.async, twitter4j.examples, twitter4j.stream" error. Does anybody know why?

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************************************")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************************************");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    }

}
```

I get this error code when I execute it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    TwitterFactory cannot be resolved to a type
    TwitterFactory cannot be resolved to a type
    Twitter cannot be resolved to a type

    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: If you don't share the actual error and stack trace (format as code) it'll be hard for someone to help.'

Comment: check now @JimGarrison

Comment: Shouldn't you be importing `org.twitter4j....` packages?

Comment: Eclipse itself recommends to import these modules.

Answer (score 0):

try to import this:

```
import twitter4j.*;
```

and also do this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb;
Twitter twitter;
cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

Comment: Still didn't work. I copy and pasted the configuration section from the twitter4j website.